# GPS icon in notification bar - Google Play Services

Tags: android, gps, speech-recognition, google-play-services, voice-recognition

I'm risking a few down-votes with this question, but today I've received a flood of user emails saying that every time my application starts, the GPS icon appears briefly in the notification bar - and I can replicate.

Pulling down the notification shade, I see 'Searching for GPS' momentarily appear - Managing to long-click it and select App-Info, it leads me to the *System UI* Application Settings.

In the logcat I see:

```
D/LocationManagerService(2358): request 448e9c20 gps Request[ACCURACY_FINE gps requested=+60m0s0ms fastest=+60m0s0ms] from com.google.android.gms(10021)
D/LocationManagerService(2358): provider request: gps ProviderRequest[ON interval=+60m0s0ms]
D/GpsLocationProvider(2358): setRequest ProviderRequest[ON interval=+60m0s0ms]
D/GpsLocationProvider(2358): startNavigating, singleShot is false
D/GpsLocationProvider_ex(2358): getSKAFEnable : false
D/GpsLocationProvider(2358): setting position_mode to MS_BASED
```

So, are any other developers having reports of this, the cause of which I assume is an update to Google Play Services?

I've changed nothing in my code (reports are coming in from users running a version 9 months old), so posting code that hasn't changed, seems a little pointless....

I thank you in advance....

EDIT - This seems to be something to do with using the Speech Recognition API as it is occurring in the Google Now application, every time you press the mic icon.

Comment: Do you use any location based features in your app? Do you request the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission in your manifest?

Comment: @ianhanniballake - Yes I do and also gms Ads. But this does not happen when such a feature is invoked. It happens when a short-lived helper Activity is activated from the Launcher. The same implementation I've used since September 2013

Comment: Having the exact same problem happening at app startup - will try to divide and conquer..